# Get all runtime storage `Orders` values from the client

Tags: polkadot-js, storage, substrate-api-client

1 the runtime storage `order` type as follow：

```rust
// Order storage
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn order)]
    pub type Orders<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        (LaneId, MessageNonce),
        Order<T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber, RingBalance<T, I>>,
        OptionQuery,
    >;
```

the auto-generated querying JS api as follow:

```javascript
      orders: AugmentedQuery<ApiType, (arg: ITuple<[LaneId, MessageNonce]> | [LaneId | string | Uint8Array, MessageNonce | AnyNumber | Uint8Array]) => Observable<Option<Order>>, [ITuple<[LaneId, MessageNonce]>]> & QueryableStorageEntry<ApiType, [ITuple<[LaneId, MessageNonce]>]>;
```

the client orders api can  only query part of orders from parameters.

**my question is that is there any way to query all orders from storage?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `entries` to get all the key value pairs from a map.

See the polkdot.js docs here: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other#map-keys--entries

The below is taken from the above link:

When working maps and double-maps, it is possible to retrieve a list of all the keys and entries for the map. For this we can use the .entries(): [StorageKey, Type][] queries. For example we may want to know the current list of validator exposures at a current era in the staking module -

```
...
// Retrieve the active era
const activeEra = await api.query.staking.activeEra();

// retrieve all exposures for the active era
const exposures = await api.query.staking.erasStakers.entries(activeEra.index);

exposures.forEach(([key, exposure]) => {
  console.log('key arguments:', key.args.map((k) => k.toHuman()));
  console.log('     exposure:', exposure.toHuman());
});
```

To understand the usage of the key.args, you need to understand that map/doublemap keys are stored alongside their lookups. This means that the raw key has hashed parts as well as the raw data. The API will decode the keys and provide the raw key arguments in args. This would mean if we are querying `api.query.staking.validators(validatorId: AccountId)` via `entries`, the key.args would be `[AccountId]`
if we are querying `api.query.staking.erasStakers(era: EraIndex, validatorId: AccountId)` via `entries`, the `key.args` would be `[EraIndex, AccountId]`